# How to use Convex Hull for SQL Server 2012 and newer

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial, convex-hull, spatial-query

I am struggling to find a straight forward answer on the internet. Hoping someone can help me out with this.

I have a dataset of customer locations with Longitude and Latitude. Each customer is part of a sales territory. Below is an example of the data headers that I have.

Table1:

```
SalesTerritory  -----  Customer -----   Longitude  -----  Latitude
```

I am trying to make a sql query that will conduct a convex hull around these territories at the Sales Territory level of detail. My end goal is to use the output on a map to show sales territories.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the lat/lng to a geography (or geometry) value then aggregate at the `SalesTerritory` level using `ConvexHullAggregate`.

```
;with geog_cte as
(
    SELECT SalesTerritory, geography::Point([Longitude], [Latitude], 4326) as customer_geog
    from Table1
)
SELECT SalesTerritory , geography::ConvexHullAggregate(customer_geog) as territory_convex_hull
FROM geog_cte 
group by SalesTerritory  ;
```

Comment: I'll point (!!) out that there's an "extended" method that makes the conversion from lat/long to a geography datatype easier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What can I say other than "Good Point"!

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you! If I had a custom coordinate system, what would I need to change 4326 to?

Comment: SQL Server supports EPSG coordinate systems so if you have a custom coordinate system then you’re not going to have a SRID that SQL will understand. Suggest you look at the EPSG systems for a best fit.

Comment: Thank you for providing guidance on how to do this. How would I go about adding a buffer to the convex hull? So that the polygon that is created has a 15 mile buffer around the outer most points?

Comment: Without wishing to sounds too mercenary I think I’ve answered the original question. Could you mark it as such please? As regards your latest question see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stbuffer-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15